# « Où » ou « quel » est le piège ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques

J'essaie de traduire l'expression anglaise

> What's the catch?

et je vois les deux constructions ci-dessus. Je pose donc la question ici : est-ce que les deux sont corrects/courants ou est-ce qu'il y en a une parmi les deux qui marche mieux ?

[D'après Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=o%C3%B9%20est%20le%20pi%C3%A8ge%2C%20quel%20est%20le%20pi%C3%A8ge&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3), il n'y a pas longtemps, « où » a devancé « quel » mais je ne suis pas sûr si je peux en tirer une conclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les deux propositions sont équivalentes mais assez soutenues. *Où est [...]* est un peu plus facile à dire mais à l'oral ou dans un texte informel, je choisirais plutôt :

> *C'est quoi, le piège ?*

ou

> *Il est où, le piège ?* (cf. [Il est où le bonheur, il est où...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVrRZ56EO9c))

[image]

Comment: Tu connais https://shiny.ens-paris-saclay.fr/app/gallicagram ?

Comment: @Personne Non, je ne connaissais pas, ça a l'air intéressant.

Answer (score 1):

En français du Québec, à l'oral populaire ou plutôt familier, on a aussi la [*pogne*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pogne#Nom_commun_3) avec l'[effacement](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Troisi%C3%A8me_personne_du_singulier_%C2%AB_elle_%C2%BB) presque complet du pronom *elle* devant le verbe *être* ; et j'omettrais toute pause :

> 'est où la pogne ? [elle est]
> C'est quoi la pogne ?

Ou avec *attrape*... Même avec *affaire*, bien moins précis mais qui évoque une situation possiblement hors de l'ordinaire. Je trouve que l'interrogatif *quel* n'est pas naturel dans ces contextes.

Answer (score -1):

On peut utiliser  dans la langue soit parlée soit écrite la construction suivante.

- En quoi consiste l'attrape ?

En anglais, le plus souvent, il n'est pas question d'un piège dans la conversation, et quelqu'un, d'emblé, introduit l'idée de piège en demandant « What's the catch? », parce qu'il y a un soupçon. Dans ce contexte il n'est pas idiomatique en français de dire « Où est le piège ? » ou de façon peu élégante « Il est où, le piège ? ». Il est plus normal de dire ceci.

- Il y a un piège / une attrape, où est-il/elle / qu'est-ce que c'est / …? (*familier : « il/elle est où ? »*)

Comment: Je suis étonné que tu proposes une acception typiquement québécoise et à ma connaissance inusitée en France. On pourrait cependant dire à Marseille : *C'est quoi, l'attrape-couillon ?*

Comment: @jlliagre C'est peu être bien québécois, mais ce n'en est pas moins français, un français qu'il ne faut pas oublier, même si une certaine majorité ne l'utilise pas, et de ce fait s'il est comparativement rare. L'éducation n'est pas un privilège de la masse, il n'en a jamais été ainsi et qui sait si même le progrès à venir changera cela. Je ne pense pas que la meilleure société des gens de lettres et autres milieux où on peut prétendre préserver une certaine culture préfère utiliser "c'est quoi" plutôt que « qu'est-ce que c'est ? ». Il est clair que ce n'est pas acceptable dans le texte formel.

Comment: *Attrape* substantif est du français, bien sûr. Je ne reprochais rien, je m'étonnais seulement. Quant à la *meilleure société des gens de lettres et autres milieux où on peut prétendre préserver une certaine culture*, j'avoue qu'elle m'inspire une certaine défiance. Je préfère ceux qui observent à ceux qui jugent.

Comment: La langue parlée familière ne relève pas d'un manque d'éducation et la culture n'y fait pas obstacle. La maîtrise des registres et des niveaux de langue et savoir comment dire et quand, c'est aussi ça la culture.

Comment: @jlliagre Cette histoire d'observation sans jugement est aberrante, une lubie anglo-saxonne, il me semble : j'observe donc je juge, et je me tais ou non.

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle  Je ne dis pas que la langue parlée familière serait utilisée nécessairement à cause d'un manque d'instruction, mais il est absolument vrai que chez l'individu qui n'a pas eu la chance d'acquérir un peu d'instruction, il ne reste pas grand chose d'autre, et même, la langue familière chez lui peut encore être plus imparfaite que chez l'individu moyennement  instruit.  Oui, un bon jugement quant à employer un mot et pas un autre, selon les circonstances, ça fait partie de la culture, mais ça ne veut surtout pas dire oublier le mot de registre supérieur.

Comment: *What does the catch consist of?* C'est un peu lourd, non ?

Comment: @jlliagre It would be "in", not "of", but it could be found a bit to formal, by some; otherwise, in a conversation about a serious subject I think there is no problem.

Comment: Too formal compared to *What's the catch?*, isn't it?

Comment: @jlliagre Si on veut préserver le registre d'un caractère, c'est trop formel; on fait de ce caractère quelqu'un d'autre, oui. Comme choix libre de traduction, à mon avis c'est beaucoup une question de gout (anglais) personnel; il me semble que, assez souvent, les anglo-saxons ne rechignent pas devant la muraille « savante » du latin et du Grec. Évidemment il y a des extrêmes, mais dans le cas présent on est loin de pouvoir parler de langage ampoulé.